# What Is The Safest Way to Run Shell Commands From PHP to Avoid Shell Running Indefinately

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to run the shell command `nproc` in PHP, so that I can simply have PHP echo back the number of CPU's available to me on the system. Looking through the PHP docs I have encountered numerous ways to execute shell commands including: [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), shell_exec(), and exec().

My question is what is the best/safest way to run shell commands from PHP. I specifically want to avoid the situation where a shell process spawned by PHP is running indefinitely in the background. A comment on the backtick operator docs page suggested that running commands with the backtick may leave processes running in the background. Is there a similar danger for the other commands? If so, what is the best way to make sure the processes spawned by these commands are terminated when completed?

Thanks!

Comment: if you do `system('./someapp &')` and background taht app, then it'll keep running even if the php script exits.

Comment: @MarcB — That's the opposite of what the question is asking for!

Comment: For this probably exec(); or shell_exec();  nproc is more if you need a 2 way communication with a child process, Generally I avoid backticks, it just looks dirty.  By the way @MarcB - "Avoid Shell Running Indefinately", just thought I would mention that :-p

Comment: which is why I'm pointing out one way for things to keep running.

Comment: @MarcB — Why are you pointing out a way to keep things running when the question wants to make sure they **do not** keep running?

Comment: why not? if OP's doing cargo cult programming and backgrounding because someone mentioned to someone else's cousin's brother's nephew's bestie at 57 flavors that a `&` does stuff, then pointing out that this is is one way things CAN keep running, logically NOT using `&` would stop things from running continously.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix thanks! I ended up using `popen` and `pclose` on the nproc process to make sure it was managed properly